# Best way to match Attribute value in XML element

Tags: xml, regex, perl, libxml2

My XML:

```
< measValue dn="Cabinet=0, Shelf=0, Card=2, Host=0">

    < r p="1">1.42</r>

    < r p="2">2.28</r>

< /measValue>
```

I want to match getAttribute("dn") with different patterns like

1> `Host=0` # this is very easy

**my solution:**

```
if (getAttribute("dn")=~ /Host=0/)
```

2> `Host=0 && Card=2`

I can do it **but I need to match it twice like**

```
if (getAttribute("dn")=~ /Host=0/) && (getAttribute("dn")=~ /Card=2/)
```

Is there any better way to accomplice this match this second pattern? using LibXML

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
if (getAttribute("dn")=~ /^(?=.*\bHost=0\b)(?=.*\bCard=2\b)/)
```

The word boundaries `\b` are here to avoid matching `myHost=01` and everything similar.

Comment: thanks!my bad for asking a silly question here...that was easy it works with \b

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has the problem that `getAttribute("dn") =~ /Card=2/` would also match a value of `Card=25` which is probably not what you want.

I would first write a helper that converts a string with key/value pairs into a hash:

```
sub key_value_pairs_to_hash {
    my $string = shift;
    my %hash;

    for my $pair (split(/\s*,\s*/, $string)) {
        my ($key, $value) = split(/\s*=\s*/, $pair, 2);
        $hash{$key} = $value;
    }

    return \%hash;
}
```

Then you can test the values like this:

```
my $hash = key_value_pairs_to_hash('Cabinet=0, Shelf=0, Card=2, Host=0');

if ($hash->{Host} == 0 && $hash->{Card} == 2) {
    print("match\n");
}
```

Comment: make sense! But there is another pain, the number of attribute matches are variable here. I may get 2 values to match or just one value to match. i.e. I may get only Card to match or Host and Card both to match. Can I keep this in some array and match it once only for all?

Comment: Yes, you can store the values to be matched in an array or a hash. If you have problems with that, please ask a separate question.